# How to remove built-in kinds' names in google datastore using kind queries

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use `google cloud datastore` kind query to get a list of kind names as demoed in the [Kind queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/metadataqueries#kind_queries),

```
query = client.query(kind='__kind__')
query.keys_only()

kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()]
```

but the code generates some built-in kind names, e.g.

```
['_AE_DatastoreAdmin_Operation', '_GAE_MR_TaskPayload',
 '__Stat_Kind_IsRootEntity__', '__Stat_Kind_NotRootEntity__',
 '__Stat_Kind__', '__Stat_PropertyName_Kind__', 
 '__Stat_PropertyType_Kind__', '__Stat_PropertyType_PropertyName_Kind__',
 '__Stat_PropertyType__', '__Stat_Total__']
```

I am wondering how to remove these built-in kind names and only retain user created kind names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those appear to be kinds of **real** entities created on the local development server/emulator - they can actually be seen in the Datastore Viewer. For example the `__Stat_*` ones are created when the datastore `Generate Stats` action is performed on the local development server.

These entities do not exist in the project's live cloud datastore (or they are stored elsewhere).

With a simple naming rule for the application's entity kinds - to not start with the `_` character - you could obtain the `kinds` list like this:

```
kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()
             if not entity.key.id_or_name.startswith('_')]
```

Depending on the `kinds` use, another option - safer IMHO from coding perspective - *might* be to always check the kind names against an explicit expected list (for example when wiping out all `kinds` entities):

```
kinds = [entity.key.id_or_name for entity in query.fetch()
             if entity.key.id_or_name in known_kinds_list]
```

Comment: Thx for the solutions. For the 2nd solution, the thing is in my scenario, I want to create a `get_tables` method, which returns all the user created kind's names. It is equivalent to `collection_names` for `pymongo.database.Database`. If I have a `known_kinds_list`, I probably don't need to get the names of all kinds.