# Auto creation of entities in blobuploadsession datastore when using upload to url functionality in blob datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, blobstore

I'm wondering if deletion of these entities in blobuploadsession would affect my app functionality or performance in any which way. The reason for deletion is when a new form is created and there were no files that were uploaded to, then it results in unnecessary entities being created.

(edit: additional info from comment)

I use blobstore (part of NDB) to store images asynchronously via upload URL functionality. When I run the app on localhost, there is an auto-creation of a datastore called *"BlobUploadSession"*. This is the entity where all the URLs for the images to be uploaded are stored as entities. When I upload a photo to the URL, it goes into the *"BlobInfo"* datastore. Now, I don't have a need of the URLs since the photo has already been uploaded. So, I'm wondering if I can delete the *BlobUploadSession* entities? Btw, *BlobUploadSession* and *BlobInfo* are default datastores automatically created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__BlobUploadSession__` and `__BlobInfo__` entities are created by and only internally used by the development server while emulating the blobstore  functionality.

There are others, similarly named `__SomeEntityName__` entities for emulating other pieces of functionality, for example a pile of them are created when you're requesting datastore stats (such function doesn't exist per-se in production).

These entities aren't created on GAE, so no need to worry about them in production.

See also related [How to remove built-in kinds' names in google datastore using kind queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379567/how-to-remove-built-in-kinds-names-in-google-datastore-using-kind-queries/42380940#42380940)